# Does a graphic or graphicsLayer support time-awareness?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, time, spatio-temporal-data, feature-layer

In the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API 2.6 I'm looking to implement map graphics. I can't see whether they support time-awareness.

The help entry for [graphicsLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/graphicslayer.htm) doesn't mention timeInfo, which is mentioned for [featureLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/featurelayer.htm).

A featureLayer is a type of graphicsLayer - but does this mean that time-awareness is only implemented at the featureLayer level?

Do I need to generate a featureLayer on-the-fly using a featureCollectionObject in order to access time-awareness and use the TimeSlider toolbar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Kelly Hutchins from the JS team at Esri, the above is correct - it is necessary to use a featureLayer to access the time-aware properties.